# Asynchronously load and unload a queue

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, queue

This code is supposed to asynchronously load a queue from a generating function.

```
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

template <typename Container>
struct LoadAsync {

    LoadAsync( size_t queue_size, function<Container()> f )
        : find_next( f ), size( queue_size ),
          worker_thread( &LoadAsync<Container>::worker_thread_function, this )
    {
        // first, build the basics
        unique_lock<mutex> lk( m );
        cv_init.wait( lk, [this] { return this->qued.size() >= this->size; } );
    }

    LoadAsync( const LoadAsync& ) = delete;

    void worker_thread_function()
    {
        while ( true ) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk( m );
            cv.wait( lk, [this] { return this->qued.size() < this->size; } );
            while ( this->qued.size() < this->size ) {
                try {
                    qued.emplace( find_next() );
                } catch (domain_error) {
                    this->size--;
                }
            }
            lk.unlock();
            cv_init.notify_one();
        }
    }

    Container pop_front()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk( m );
        cv_init.wait( lk, [this] { return this->qued.size() >= this->size; } );
        if (this->qued.size() == 0)
            throw out_of_range("out of range");
        auto front = move( qued.front() );
        qued.pop();
        lk.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
        return front;
    }

  private:
    size_t size;
    queue<Container> qued;
    function<Container()> find_next;
    thread worker_thread;
    mutex m;
    condition_variable cv;
    condition_variable cv_init;
};

int main()
{
    auto func = []() {
        static int which = 1;
        if ( which < 10 )
            return which++;
        else
            throw domain_error("out of range");
    };

    LoadAsync<int> la( 3, func );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 11; ++i ) cout << la.pop_front() << endl;

}
```

Is this a good approach?  Are there any gotchas here in using `condition_variable`s?  Are there any long bottlenecks here?  Is waiting on a condition variable an immediate thing?

Comment: Hey, i can not answer your questions but i wanted to recommend you a great talk about "Lock-Free Programming" by Herb Sutter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1gO9aB9nbs (He is also talking - amongst other things - about lock-free queues)

Answer (score 1):

I see one instance of **undefined behavior** in your code.

```
LoadAsync( size_t queue_size, function<Container()> f )
        : find_next( f ), size( queue_size ),
          worker_thread( &LoadAsync<Container>::worker_thread_function, this )
...

void worker_thread_function()
{
    while ( true ) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk( m );

...

thread worker_thread;
mutex m;
```

The `LoadAsync` constructor constructs each member variable in the order in which they were declared — i.e., it constructs `this->worker_thread` before constructing `this->m`. And the way you construct `worker_thread` causes it to start running *immediately*, and the first thing it does is attempt to lock `m` — whose constructor may not have finished yet!

The simplest solution is to reorder your member variables so that `worker_thread` will be constructed last.

---

Style notes:

- `using namespace std;` is a bad idea, and you shouldn't do it (especially in a header file like this). Explicitly qualify `std::mutex`, `std::domain_error`, and so on. It's a good habit to get into.
- `&LoadAsync<Container>::worker_thread_function` is a verbose way of saying `&LoadAsync::worker_thread_function`: the `<Container>` part is implied in this context, just as it is in your copy-constructor declaration.
- You don't need to explicitly `= delete` your copy-constructor: since one of your non-static member variables is a non-movable `std::mutex`, your class itself becomes non-movable by default.
- `cv` and `cv_init` are bad names. Consider `cv_consume` and `cv_produce`, or `cv_queue_empty` and `cv_queue_full`. (Also, it's strange that your `pop_front` will block waiting for the producer to finish running `find_next()` even when the queue *isn't* empty. Doesn't that basically defeat the purpose of having two threads?)
- `qued` is a weird name; perhaps you meant `q` or `queue`?
- `Container` is a bad name for the object type *being contained by* your queue. I suggest renaming it `T`.

---

You don't provide any way to clean up after your `worker_thread`. By default, `std::thread`'s destructor simply blocks until the thread finishes, which (since your worker thread is just an infinite loop) means that destroying a `LoadAsync` object will hang forever.

Calling `worker_thread.detach()` is one solution, but will still "leak resources" in a sense. It would be better to change the `worker_thread`'s condition from `while (true)` to something like `while (!this->finished)`, change your predicate from

```
[this] { return this->qued.size() < this->size; }
```

to

```
[this] { return finished || (qued.size() < size); }
```

and then change the body of the destructor to

```
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
    this->finished = true;
}
this->cv.notify_one();
this->worker_thread.join();
```

---

It's bad practice to call the user-provided function `find_next()` while holding the lock on `m`. Consider what would happen if `find_next` tried to take the same lock:

```
bool first = true;
LoadAsync<int> la(3, [&]() {
    return first ? (first = false, 42) : la.pop_front() + 1;
});
```

The easiest solution is to drop the lock, call `find_next()`, and then reacquire the lock to move the result into the queue. Of course, the move-constructor of `Container` might take the lock...

Also, notice that if `find_next` throws anything *other* than `std::domain_error`, your program will die in `std::terminate`. That's not so good.

---

Lastly, notice that you're relying on the notion of a "producer thread" and a "consumer thread" being able to run concurrently with each other. If your program is running in a context so resource-constrained that it can only get hold of a single thread, then your code will deadlock. IMHO that's extremely unlikely, and even if it did happen I would hope that `thread`'s constructor would throw an exception instead of blithely continuing on its way. But I don't know.